# Include Owner and Editor metadata in list item Details panel

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, column, list-form, properties

One of my users recently moved from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint Online (modern ux). She asked me how to display the "Created by [name]" and "Last Modified by [name]" in the details panel of a list/library item. She sent me a screenshot showing that it's displayed by default in SharePoint 2007:

[image: SP2007 displaying created by/modified by user information]

I created a new list and test item in my lab tenant and verified her report. Using calculated columns, I was able to get the Created/Modified *dates* to appear, but not the owner/editor metadata.

[image]

In addition to using a calculated column, I've tried using a Lookup column but that also did not make this particular information available as a selection. I tried using the List/Item Properties web parts, but they didn't allow that column to be displayed either.

I know the user can easily build views, etc to get this information. But they are accustomed to simply clicking on an item to see all the information they need. I imagine I can create a custom form in PowerApps to facilitate this but I'd like to exhaust any native SharePoint options to address this before I take that on.

Answer (score 0):

You could check that under more details. Like the below screenshot shows:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to bring that up with just one click like the properties panel? Getting to the details is a multi-click (or click/scroll) process. My users have to gather data from thousands of files daily so adding one or two steps is a bigger deal that it might seem.

I can't think of any possible rational as to why the most foundational bits of metadata are not included in the basic properties by default. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Maybe you could use powerapps to customize the form to display the information.